# How to publish a JSP Webpage created with Netbeans?

Tags: publishing, web

I want to allow others to access my website created through Netbeans but I don't know how to do so. Ive searched and I found that you had to buy webservers and domain names?

However, I only want to host the webpage using my own computer since it isn't really anything commercial. How can I publish the webpage using Netbeans or my own computer? Would using IIS of Windows be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can download or use (if you have installed) [Apache-Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/deployer-howto.html) to deploy your web-app on your local machine.

Text from the above mentioned link.

> It is possible to deploy web applications to a running Tomcat server.
>
> If the Host autoDeploy attribute is "true", the Host will attempt to
>   deploy and update web applications dynamically, as needed, for example
>   if a new .WAR is dropped into the appBase. For this to work, the Host
>   needs to have background processing enabled which is the default
>   configuration.